# Background Color to a specific value is not changing after sorting JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Please suggest changes to my code. Background Color to a specific value is not changing after sorting `JTable`.

### Java form code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class Technicain_Report extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rs1 = null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;

    location Location = new location();
            String loc = Location.url;
            String user = Location.user;
            String pass = Location.pass ;

            String Serpass = null ;
                String userlogger ;
                  TableModel model ;

    public Technicain_Report() {
        initComponents();

    }

     public Technicain_Report(String pass) {
        initComponents();

        mob.setSelected(true);
        comp.setSelected(false);
        userlogger = pass ;


        model = techrprt.getModel();


              this.setTitle("Technician Report - " + userlogger);  
((DefaultTableCellRenderer)techrprt.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                filler();


      TableColumnModel columnModel = techrprt.getColumnModel();
columnModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(15);
columnModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
columnModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(30);
columnModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(20);
columnModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(130);
columnModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(20);

      sort();

    }


    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        table = new javax.swing.JTable();
        buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        techrprt = new javax.swing.JTable()

        {
            @Override

            public Component prepareRenderer (TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
                Component componenet = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);

                //  int selrow =  techrprt.getSelectedRow();

                //  int index =  techrprt.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(selrow);

                Object value = getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex,columnIndex);

                if(columnIndex == 5){

                    if(value.equals("NEW"))
                    {

                        componenet.setBackground(Color.RED);
                        componenet.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                    }

                }

                else {

                    componenet.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    componenet.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                }

                return componenet;

            }
        }

        ;
        mobsrch = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        mob = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        comp = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        shwdlvd = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();

        table.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));
        table.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "SL NO.", "NAME", "MOBILE NO.", "SELECT"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, true
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setRowMargin(2);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setSelectionForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table);

        setTitle("Technician Report");

        techrprt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 204, 204));
        techrprt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        techrprt.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "SER. NO.", "CUSTOMER NAME", "MOBILE NO.", "CATEGORY", "MODEL", "STATUS"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        techrprt.setRowHeight(20);
        techrprt.setRowMargin(2);
        techrprt.setSelectionForeground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        techrprt.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        techrprt.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                servicepass(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(techrprt);
        techrprt.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        if (techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
            techrprt.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false);
        }

        mobsrch.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                mobsrchCaretPositionChanged(evt);
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                mobsrchInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        mobsrch.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                mobsrchActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        mobsrch.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                mobsrchKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("Search");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        mob.setText("Mobile");
        mob.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                mobMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        comp.setText("Company Name");
        comp.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                compMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        shwdlvd.setText("Show Delivered Items");
        shwdlvd.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                shwdlvdMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        shwdlvd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                shwdlvdActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 883, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(shwdlvd)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(mob)
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55)
                        .addComponent(comp))
                    .addComponent(mobsrch, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 211, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(36, 36, 36))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(mob)
                            .addComponent(comp)
                            .addComponent(shwdlvd))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(mobsrch, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 541, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(927, 650));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void mobsrchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    filtercheck();
    }                                        

    private void compMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
       mob.setSelected(false);
    }                                 

    private void mobMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
     comp.setSelected(false);
    }                                

    private void mobsrchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
            if (evt.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        filtercheck();
            }
    }                                   

    private void shwdlvdActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    private void shwdlvdMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    filler();

    }                                    

    private void mobsrchInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                               

        buttonclicker();


    }                                              

    private void mobsrchCaretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                             
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              jButton1.doClick();
            }
        }, 
        1000 
);

    }                                            

    private void servicepass(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                             

        int selrow =  techrprt.getSelectedRow();

        int index =  techrprt.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(selrow);

        String value1 = model.getValueAt(index, 0).toString();

        new Service_Details( user, value1).setVisible(true);

    }                            

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Technicain_Report.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Technicain_Report.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Technicain_Report.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Technicain_Report.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Technicain_Report().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    public void filler(){


        String sql  ;

  try {

     if("admin".equals(userlogger)  )
     {
          if(shwdlvd.isSelected())
          {
          sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice ";
          }
          else
          {
              sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where contactNo <> 'd' ";
          }
     }
     else
     {
         if(shwdlvd.isSelected())
         {
          sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where SalesMan = '"+userlogger+"' ";
         }
         else
         {
              sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where SalesMan = '"+userlogger+"' and contactNo <> 'd' ";
         }
     }
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) techrprt.getModel();
      model.setRowCount(0);

           con =DriverManager.getConnection( loc , user, pass);
                pst =con.prepareStatement(sql);
               rs=pst.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()){

     String  data1 = rs.getString("No");
     String data2 = rs.getString("customerName");
       String data4 = rs.getString("makeAndModel");
      String   data5 = rs.getString("imeiNo");
       String     data6 = rs.getString("contactNo");
   String data21 ;
    String data23;
     String ctn = data2;
     String sql123;


        sql123  ="select * from tblaccountmaster WHERE AccountCode = '"+ctn+"' ";


           con =DriverManager.getConnection( loc , user, pass);
            pst =con.prepareStatement(sql123);
               rs1=pst.executeQuery();
               while(rs1.next()){

     data21 = rs1.getString("AccountName");

     data23 = rs1.getString("ContactNumber");          

   Object[] row = { data1 ,data21,data23,data4,data5,data6};

    model.addRow(row);  

               }
  }
  con.close();  
  }catch(SQLException Ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(login.classgetName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,Ex);
         }



    }


     public void filtercheck()
     {
             String text1 = mobsrch.getText();

         String sql  ;

  try {

     if("admin".equals(userlogger)  )
     {
          if(shwdlvd.isSelected())
          {
          sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice ";
          }
          else
          {
              sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where contactNo <> 'd' ";
          }
     }
     else
     {
         if(shwdlvd.isSelected())
         {
          sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where SalesMan = '"+userlogger+"' ";
         }
         else
         {
              sql ="select * from tbl_serviceInvoice where SalesMan = '"+userlogger+"' and contactNo <> 'd' ";
         }
     }
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) techrprt.getModel();
      model.setRowCount(0);

           con =DriverManager.getConnection( loc , user, pass);
                pst =con.prepareStatement(sql);
               rs=pst.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()){

     String  data1 = rs.getString("No");
     String data2 = rs.getString("customerName");
       String data4 = rs.getString("makeAndModel");
      String   data5 = rs.getString("imeiNo");
       String     data6 = rs.getString("contactNo");
   String data21 ;
    String data23;
     String ctn = data2;
     String sql123 ; 
     if("".equals(text1))
     {
    sql123 ="select * from tblaccountmaster WHERE AccountCode = '"+ctn+"'  ";
     }
     else
     {
         if(mob.isSelected())
         {
            sql123 ="select * from tblaccountmaster WHERE AccountCode = '"+ctn+"' and ContactNumber like  '%"+text1+"%' ";
         }
         else
         {
              sql123 ="select * from tblaccountmaster WHERE AccountCode = '"+ctn+"' and AccountName like  '%"+text1+"%' ";
         }
     }

           con =DriverManager.getConnection( loc , user, pass);
            pst =con.prepareStatement(sql123);
               rs1=pst.executeQuery();
               while(rs1.next()){

     data21 = rs1.getString("AccountName");

     data23 = rs1.getString("ContactNumber");          

   Object[] row = { data1 ,data21,data23,data4,data5,data6};

    model.addRow(row);  

               }
  }
  con.close();  
  }catch(SQLException Ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(login.classgetName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,Ex);
         }



     }


     public void sort()
                  {    

         DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) techrprt.getModel();
         TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(dm);
         techrprt.setRowSorter(sorter);




     }

     public void buttonclicker()
     {
          new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              jButton1.doClick();
            }
        }, 
        1000 
);



     }


         public void coloring()
         {}



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.ButtonGroup buttonGroup1;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton comp;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton mob;
    private javax.swing.JTextField mobsrch;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox shwdlvd;
    private javax.swing.JTable table;
    private javax.swing.JTable techrprt;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

### Customized code for `JTable`

```
techrprt = new javax.swing.JTable()

{
    @Override

    public Component prepareRenderer (TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
        Component componenet = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);

        //  int selrow =  techrprt.getSelectedRow();

        //  int index =  techrprt.getRowSorter().convertRowIndexToModel(selrow);

        Object value = getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex,columnIndex);

        if(columnIndex == 5){

            if(value.equals("NEW"))
            {

                componenet.setBackground(Color.RED);
                componenet.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

            }

        }

        else {

            componenet.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            componenet.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return componenet;

    }
};
```

When I sort the columns, the background color for value "new" is at the same initial position. It's not getting updated when I sort columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object value = getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex,columnIndex);
```

The data in the model is never sorted, only the view is sorted.

So you should be using:

```
Object value = getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
```

That is get the data from the view. The view knows about the sorted order and will return the proper value.